# --shell stops execution, for Command Prompt, Batch files, PHP exec(), and more

Tags: php, shell, batch-file, command-prompt, inkscape

**What I want**

I have a command I was to execute. When I do this manually with command prompt, one command at a time, I have no issues. I am trying to automate this.

**What I have tried**

Here is what I type manually into command prompt. I have also tried using a `.bat` file.

```
cd c:/Program Files/Inkscape
inkscape --shell
c:/wamp/www/i/t1.svg --export-png=c:/wamp/www/i/r1.png --export-dpi=900
```

Here is an attempt using php `exec()`.

```
exec('cd c:/Program Files/Inkscape && inkscape --shell && c:/wamp/www/i/t1.svg --export-png=c:/wamp/www/i/r1.png --export-dpi=900');
```

**What is happening**

Debugging using `echo`, it is clear that `--shell` is causing the execution to stop. When running the batch file, the batch closes at that command. When running php `exec()`, no more commands work after that command is called. When I execute that command manually over command prompt, I get this response.

```
Inkscape 0.91 r13725 interactive shell mode. Type 'quit' to quit.
```

After this, I can run the next command I need to run. I can't, however, run this command.

```
inkscape --shell && c:/wamp/www/i/t1.svg --export-png=c:/wamp/www/i/r1.png --export-dpi=900
```

I get the same response, and the actions after `--shell` are not taken.

When I removed `--shell` from both the batch file, it gives me an inkscape error

```
(inkscape.exe:11912): Gtk-WARNING **: Could not find the icon 'object-visible'.
The 'hicolor' theme was not found either, perhaps you need to install it.
You can get a copy from:
http://icon-theme.freedesktop.org/releases
(inkscape.exe:11912): Gdk-CRITICAL **: inner_clipboard_window_procedure: assertion 'success' failed
```

The `exec` function without `--shell` results in the file to never finish loading.

**What I need**

It can be a batch file, php `exec()` function, or any other method to accomplish this command, as long as it can be automated. Please explain your answer so I can understand executing commands a little bit better.

**Update: What Workers**

Thanks to both answers for help in figuring this out.

In inkscape, I had to create a folder in `Inkscape/share/icons` named `hicolor`, and in that folder, place an empty file called `index.theme`. Then, I had to correct my syntax to be this.

```
cd c:/Program Files/Inkscape && inkscape --file=t1.svg --export-eps=r1.eps --export-dpi=900)
```

Comment: The "interactive shell mode" phrase is rather self-explanatory. You want Inkscape to be *not* interactive, since you won't be there to hit the keyboard.

Comment: IIRC, interactive mode takes commands from stdin.  My answer below provides a possible solution that uses this, though I have no idea if it'll work in Microsoft Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to any Windows-specific behaviour here, but ... Inkscape's `--shell` option may take commands from standard input.  If that works the same in your environment as it would in a Unix system, then there may be an easy solution.

First off, note the notation you've used in your `exec()`:

```
commandone && commandtwo
```

This is *not* the same as typing one line (commandone) and then typing another line (commandtwo).  Instead, what it does is to run commandone, and if it *completes* (finishes) successfully, run commandtwo.  This is obviously not what you want.

Instead, in a Unix environment, you might try something like this:

```
echo "somestring" | commandone
```

This makes "somestring" the input to "commandone", as if you had typed it into the terminal.  In your case, this might look something like this:

```
echo "c:/wamp/www/i/t1.svg --export-png=c:/wamp/www/i/r1.png --export-dpi=900" | inkscape --shell
```

The effect is that you take a *string*, and you echo it .. but you pipe the **stdout** through a command (`inkscape --shell`) which accepts **stdin**.

Alternately if you are using `bash` as your shell, another notation might be:

```
inkscape --shell <<<"c:/wamp/www/i/t1.svg --export-png=c:/wamp/www/i/r1.png --export-dpi=900"
```

This is possibly easier to read, in that it puts the important command at the beginning of the line.  The `<<<` tells bash to "take the following string, and feed it to the preceding command", or thereabouts.

To put this into PHP exec(), I would recommend using the first notation, because I have no idea whether your Windows environment uses bash or some other shell to execute command lines.

Try the "echo" line above in your Windows shell, and see what happens.  It may just work.  I guarantee nothing.  :-)

Your final PHP code might look something like this:

```
$inkscape="c:/Program Files/Inkscape/Inkscape --shell";
$cmd="c:/wamp/www/i/t1.svg --export-png=c:/wamp/www/i/r1.png --export-dpi=900";

exec(sprintf("echo '%s' | %s", $cmd, $inkscape), $output, $retval);
if ($retval!==false) {
  print "Success!\n";
}
```

Needless to say, this is untested, YMMV, may contain nuts.  But perhaps it helps.  ;-)

---

**UPDATE:**

After having looked at [the Inkscape man page](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/inkscape-man.html), it looks like you could handle this through a pure command line, without the need for a pipe and `--shell`.

What about just this?

```
exec("c:/Program Files/Inkscape/Inkscape --file=c:/wamp/www/i/t1.svg --export-png=c:/wamp/www/i/r1.png --export-dpi=900", $output, $retval);

if ($retval>0)
    printf("ERROR (%d): %s\n", $retval, implode("\n", $output));
```

?

Comment: Definitely worth trying. You missed a semi colon on the second line of your last code snippit. Anyways, I'm actually trying to get this to run on a windows environment and a linux environment. On the windows environment, you code seems to not work at all, but on linux, it gives success, but returns linux code 127, which suggests command could not be found. I rewrote your line as this `exec(sprintf("echo '%s' | %s", $cmd, $inkscape), $output, $retval);` and now get a 126, found but could not be executed. I'll keep digging into it and see what I can get.

Comment: Also added a pure-command-line option that looks like it should work. I don't think you need `--shell`.  Of course, this is still all untested on my end.

Comment: You missed a cd, but other than that, I'm getting `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.` Looking into it.

Comment: I've got it working! Unfortunately, now I'm facing the missing files issues I have with the other answer. Gotta figure out how to easily replace all the missing files, or what I'm suppose to do with `index.theme`. I definitely learned a lot from your help, thank you.

Comment: I have found a solution. I don't have time at the moment to go into detail. I'll return tomorrow with my fix for anyone in the future who is interested.

Comment: Updated my answer with the solution found. You may update yours as well to reflect this.

Comment: Happy that I could help. Regarding the `cd`, I didn't forget it, I think you probably don't need it.  If you call the `inkscape.exe` binary with a fully qualified path, and you specify your input `--file` and output `--export-png` also fully qualified, then the current working directory would seem to be irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the docs, --shell is for interactive use only as if you are typing into a terminal.  Try removing this flag.  You need your CLI program to execute on the command line in a non-interactive mode in order to trigger it from PHP.

Here are the options: https://inkscape.org/en/doc/inkscape-man.html

Comment: I've tried removing `--shell` from both the batch file and the `exec()` function. The batch file gives an inkscape error `(inkscape.exe:11912): Gtk-WARNING **: Could not find the icon 'object-visible'.
The 'hicolor' theme
was not found either, perhaps you need to install it.
You can get a copy from:
        http://icon-theme.freedesktop.org/releases
(inkscape.exe:11912): Gdk-CRITICAL **: inner_clipboard_window_procedure: asserti
on 'success' failed`. I'll look into that. The `exec` function results in the file loading forever.

Comment: Do you get that error on running the batch file on the command line?  It looks possibly like a bug in inkscape: https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1329990

Comment: It is. I'm not sure what this means. Currently I'm replacing the missing files one at a time. Not sure how many there are, or if this will fix the problem. Is there a way to keep this warning from stopping the program from running?

Comment: I'm guessing there are not a lot of options.  One approach might be to try installing a newer or older version of inkscape.  Or reinstalling (in case something in the install is corrupted).  Otherwise, it sounds like some people in the bug report resolved the problem by creating the missing folders and empty files.

Comment: I'm trying to add the missing files, but I've already created a dozen and I'm not sure how many more there are. Is there a way to get a list of all missing files or download the missing files, or automate this in some way?

Comment: From the error, it sounds like there's an entire package missing, that can be downloaded from http://icon-theme.freedesktop.org/releases.    What this installed via a software repo?  You might look if there are other inkscape packages available for install.  They may have all the dependancies.

Comment: I have, and I found this single file in a double zip `index.theme`. Where does this belong. Isn't this a windows theme file?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Just googling a bit, it looks like it might be somewhere under C:\Program Files\Inkscape\share\themes\

Comment: Nope. No theme files. Nothing that looks remotely like that's where it's suppose to be.